# How to zoom out on Firefox driver using Mac?

Tags: python, macos, selenium, firefox, zooming

I try to figure out how to zoom in on Firefox driver using Selenium on a Mac. When I try to use the `send_keys()` method on the `html` element, nothing happens (no action). The action method gets no action neither.

When I try to use the `pyautogui module` instead, the code works on Windows but not on `Mac`. It actually zooms out to 120% on the Mac?

Which is the best way to solve this?

```
# IMPORTS
from sys import platform
import os

import pyautogui
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True

import time

import tkinter as tk

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox, FirefoxOptions
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
# import Action chains 
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service

class Driver():
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.driver = Firefox(service=self.service_path, options=self.opts)

        #open url
        self.driver.get("https://google.com/")
        
        #zoom out
        time.sleep(3)
        
        self.html = self.driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "html")
        
        
        self.html.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND, Keys.SUBTRACT)
        
        
        # #create action chain object
        # self.action = ActionChains(self.driver)
        
        # self.action.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND, Keys.SUBTRACT)
        
        # # perform the operation
        # self.action.perform()
        
        
        # if platform == "win32":
        #     pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', '-') #zoom out to 67% 
        #     pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', '-')
        #     pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', '-')
            
        # if platform == "darwin":
            
        #     pyautogui.hotkey('command', '-') #this actually zoom in ro 120% ?! 
        #     pyautogui.hotkey('command', '-')
        #     pyautogui.hotkey('command', '-')

Driver()
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to zoom out after testing several methods. See below:

```
    # 1
    # id_root = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "root")
    #self.driver.execute_script("$('#root').css('zoom', 5);")
    
    # 2
    #self.driver.execute_script("document.body.style.MozTransform='scale(0.8)';")
    
    # 3
    #self.driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='50%';")
    
    
    # 4 
    #self.html = self.driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "html")
    #self.html.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND, Keys.SUBTRACT)
    
    # 5
           # if platform == "win32":
    #     pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', '-') #zoom out 3 times
    #     pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', '-')
    #     pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', '-')
        
    # if platform == "darwin":
        
    #     pyautogui.hotkey('COMMAND', '-') #zoom out
    #     pyautogui.hotkey('COMMAND', '-')
    #     pyautogui.hotkey('COMMAND', '-')
    
    #6 - This works!
    self.driver.set_context("chrome")
    win = self.driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "html")
    win.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + "-" + "-" + "-")
    self.driver.set_context("content")
```